# How to generate individual ledgers for individual participants

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I'm new to Blockchain. I heard that blockchain provides individual ledgers for individual participants. I want to know how it will work with Hyperledger Composer Blockchain application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyperledger Composer is built on Hyperledger Fabric - which  is a permissioned, distributed, **shared** ledger.

If you are new to Composer, I would suggest working through [the documentation](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/index.html), in particular the tutorials.

More information on Fabric is available in [the Fabric documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: I have a web application , i need to connect my application with blockchain network . Which one i need to use either Fabric or Composer.